# Autocorrelation Plot Using tikz and pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to reproduce the figure of an autocorrelation plot from the python statsmodels package below using pgfplots/tikz packages on Latex.

[image]

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Just compute the point coordinates in Python, "copy paste" it to TikZ to draw the figures.